# Database Jquery - Column Headers Misalign when using ScrollY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using jQuery's DataTables and Bootstrap. So the problem I have is that when I switch between tabs of "completed" and "dead", the "dead" tab's column headers get bunched up on the left until I click on them and then they align themselves correctly. This happens whenever I refresh. I tried using CSS with overflow:auto, but that makes my whole panel scrollable, which I don't want. I want the headers to stay fixed while i scroll through the table.

```
  <div class = 'row'>
  <div class='col-lg-11'>

  <div id="pane3" > 
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a  href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">My Completed</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a  href="#4b" id="deadTab"  data-toggle="tab">Dead Requests</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
      <div class='tab-pane active' id ="4a">
        <!-- <div id="" style=" width: 100%; position:relative; height:200px;"> -->
          <table id='completed' class="table table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Req. #</th>
              <th>Project #</th>
              <th>Client Name</th>
              <th>Program</th>
              <th>Request Type</th>
              <th>Assignee</th>
              <th>Completed Date</th>
              <th>Clone</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      <!--   </div> -->
        </div>
          <div class='tab-pane' id ="4b">
         <!--  <div id="" style=" overflow:auto; position:relative; "> -->
            <table id='dead' class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Req. #</th>
                <th>Project #</th>
                <th>Client Name</th>
                <th>Program</th>
                <th>Request Type</th>
                <th>Assignee</th>
                <th>Dead Date</th>
                <th>Restart</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>July</td>
              <td>Dooley</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>john@e</td>
              <td>july@example.com</td>
              <td>6/12/2017</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
         <!--  </div> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {



   $('#completed').DataTable( {
    "paging":false,
    // "fixedHeader": true,
    "scrollY": "140px",
    "table-layout":"fixed",
    "columnDefs":[
    {"width":60, "targets":0},
    {"width":60, "targets":1},
    {"width":60, "targets":2},
    {"width":60, "targets":3},
    {"width":90, "targets":4},
    {"width":90, "targets":5},
    {"width":90, "targets":6},
    {"width":90, "targets":7},
    ]

  });


  $('#dead').DataTable( {
    "paging":false,
    "fixedHeader": true,
    "scrollY": "140px",
    "table-layout":"fixed",
     "columnDefs":[
    {"width":60, "targets":0},
    {"width":60, "targets":1},
    {"width":60, "targets":2},
    {"width":60, "targets":3},
    {"width":90, "targets":4},
    {"width":90, "targets":5},
    {"width":90, "targets":6},
    {"width":90, "targets":7},
    ]

    // "table-layout":"fixed"



  });





});



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your other tab is hidden (`display: none`). You can initialize your data table after `dead` tab is shown like this:

```js
$('#completed').DataTable({
  "paging": false,
  // "fixedHeader": true,
  "scrollY": "140px",
  "table-layout": "fixed",
  "columnDefs": [{
      "width": 60,
      "targets": 0
    },
    {
      "width": 60,
      "targets": 1
    },
    {
      "width": 60,
      "targets": 2
    },
    {
      "width": 60,
      "targets": 3
    },
    {
      "width": 90,
      "targets": 4
    },
    {
      "width": 90,
      "targets": 5
    },
    {
      "width": 90,
      "targets": 6
    },
    {
      "width": 90,
      "targets": 7
    },
  ]

});






$('#deadTab').one('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  $('#dead').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "fixedHeader": true,
    "scrollY": "140px",
    "table-layout": "fixed",
    "columnDefs": [{
        "width": 60,
        "targets": 0
      },
      {
        "width": 60,
        "targets": 1
      },
      {
        "width": 60,
        "targets": 2
      },
      {
        "width": 60,
        "targets": 3
      },
      {
        "width": 90,
        "targets": 4
      },
      {
        "width": 90,
        "targets": 5
      },
      {
        "width": 90,
        "targets": 6
      },
      {
        "width": 90,
        "targets": 7
      },
    ]

    // "table-layout":"fixed"

  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-11'>
      <div id="pane3">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">My Completed</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#4b" id="deadTab" data-toggle="tab">Dead Requests</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class='tab-pane active' id="4a">
            <!-- <div id="" style=" width: 100%; position:relative; height:200px;"> -->
            <table id='completed' class="table table-striped table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Req. #</th>
                  <th>Project #</th>
                  <th>Client Name</th>
                  <th>Program</th>
                  <th>Request Type</th>
                  <th>Assignee</th>
                  <th>Completed Date</th>
                  <th>Clone</th>

                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <!--   </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class='tab-pane' id="4b">
            <!--  <div id="" style=" overflow:auto; position:relative; "> -->
            <table id='dead' class="table table-striped table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Req. #</th>
                  <th>Project #</th>
                  <th>Client Name</th>
                  <th>Program</th>
                  <th>Request Type</th>
                  <th>Assignee</th>
                  <th>Dead Date</th>
                  <th>Restart</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>July</td>
                  <td>Dooley</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>john@e</td>
                  <td>july@example.com</td>
                  <td>6/12/2017</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Form</button></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <!--  </div> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```